# How to plot graph in Excel from function output value?

Tags: graph, excel-2010

In MS Excel 2010 , I am trying to plot a graph based on the value extracted from a functional output.

**Example :** Assume In SHEET1 A1 cell contains a data  ***38.217 (Physical Data rate)***.
In SHEET2 I extract only numerical value and trim off the alphabetical characters. so, I am using this formula **=LEFT(SHEET1!A1,6)**. I am getting required value **38.217** but I am unable to plot the graph using this value. Its not recognizing as a numerical value. It is recognizing as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=LEFT is a text function that returns a string. Wrap it in `=Value(  )`.